# salesforce for outlook: MSI vs. user download?

Tags: force.com, salesforce-for-outlook

I'm trying to understand the pro/cons about doing a an install via .msi vs giving our users a link to dl salesforce for outlook.   Our company is upgrading from  XP to windows 7.  Corporate security is really not an issue, as the link has been cleared for download.

**Can i do any extra configuration by the MSI?** any type of pros cons would be helpful as this is brand new territory for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSI files can be pushed to client machines automatically via a number of tools, including Microsoft's Active Directory.

Offering software in both exe and MSI installer is common in the enterprise space so that the MSI can be used for automated deployment across your user base - who often don't have rights under their own accounts to install software.

If this doesn't sound like it applies to you the exe is likely easier.

Comment: Thanks! can i do any extra configuration by the msi? that's my  concern

Comment: Good question, afraid that depends on what admin tools you're using to deploy and gets more into the specifics of the plugin that I know enough to answer.

Comment: okay. i think we're going to do the .exe installer... thanks @ca_peterson